# Exchange data between iOS app and Mac app through USB cable

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I'm looking for a way to exchange data between my own iOS app and my own OS X application through a cable.
I know there have to be frameworks to connect to the device from inside a Mac application, apps like iExplore can import and export files from the device.

It doesn't matter in which way the data is exchanged as long as it's through a cable. It may use the filesystem, or if I can get the device on the same network as the Mac through a connection or even use 3rd party hardware. 
It doesn't matter if it uses private APIs or if the device needs a jailbreak, it is for internal use only.

Thanks in advance.

IMPORTANT: the solution can't feature anything wireless, no wifi, no bluetooth, no cellular tethering, the data exchange should work even with the device in airplane mode. This is the main requirement. 
And it has to be relatively fast. I want to exchange small packages less than 1 kB once every few seconds. The delay between send and receive should be as little as possible, 1 second is the longest acceptable delay.

Comment: The Accessory framework maybe

Comment: Go ahead, keep looking.  Come back when you have an actual problem.  The hint above seems valid enough :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at https://bitbucket.org/tristero/ipodaccessframework which can get/put files into an applications private document directory, provided you know its application bundle id.